# How could possibly gl_ReadPixels depend on shader complexity?

Tags: android, opengl-es, timing

I'm writing an app for Android that uses fragment shaders for image processing. I'm using two FBOs with textures as color attachments so that I can flip the fbos and make more than one pass over the initial image.

All is well as the app works just fine. However, I'm trying to do some timing using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `GLES20.glFinish()` between successive OpenGL calls.

What I see from the timings astonishes me. Firstly, the timings are quite stable between different runs. Secondly, the `glReadPixels` call seems to depend on my shader's complexity, i.e. if the GPU spends more time processing the image, it spends more time reading the pixels from the FBO texture. Mind you, I've put `GLES20.glFinish()` before calling `GLES20.glReadPixels`, but it doesn't make any difference whether I put it or not.

Do you have any clue as to why such dependency might exist? Is it an Android-based issue, i.e. Android is not executing the `glFinish()` calls at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried profiling the GPU using glFinish as well and gave up - it doesn't seem to fully block as you'd think it would. I assume the driver simply has a pretty loose interpretation of what glFinish is supposed to do. Maybe this is also a driver-specific issue.

Comment: Really? You know, I think that implementing `glFinish` correctly would significantly increase driver code complexity so possibly they are just not implementing it because it's rarely used? But after all it's in the API so how could we be sure it's indeed not working and I'm not getting it wrong...

Comment: It could simply be because of the complex nature of the GPU - maybe it does wait until the command buffer is processed but not until the pixels are rendered. But they may as well just not have implemented it (we're working with a light version of a light version of OpenGL, after all). In any case, your best bet is to probably render your scene multiple times, measure start and end, and then iterate using that. Crude, but hey, welcome to mobile game development!

Comment: Haha. Here I come, then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EboMike, you are a pro game dev, then? Very honoured to have talked to you!

Comment: @EboMike - This matches what I've seen.  On the tile-based deferred renderers of the PowerVR series, any glGet* or glRead* operations halt the rendering pipeline at that point until you get a result back.  Modifications to earlier operations can have their impact be deferred until you hit one of these halting points, appearing to slow them down.

Comment: @Brad Larson - I'm trying it exactly on such kind of a GPU - SGX540 on an OMAP4.

Comment: @Albus - I am, although I will openly admit that I'm an complete OpenGL ES n00b and only write OpenGL ES stuff in my free time. At work, it's DX and GCM for me. Good luck with your game!

Comment: @EboMike thank you! Just to clarify - I'm not making a game but trying to do some image processing on the GPU, i.e. trying to do some GPGPU stuff ;-)